# TTURLJSONResponse Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: iphone, ios4

Good Day!

I tried to recreate the sample TTFacebook Project of the three20 samples in an XCode4 IDE, but I got this error about TTURLJSONResponse

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TTURLJSONResponse", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FacebookSearchFeed.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

thanks, much love and respect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you added Three20:extThree20JSON+YAJL or Three20:extThree20JSON+SBJSON to your project (either manually or via ttmodule.py), also make sure they compile fine (look if the binaries are not red in your project Build Phases).

Comment: Adding manually the TTURLJSONResponse Source Files in the project solve the question by the way, the ttmodule.py didn't include the JSONResponse :)

Comment: if i add it through terminal, how would it look like, i always get an error "Unable to open the project file at this path"